# Python: add multiple values foreach

Tags: python, automated-tests

Working with Selenium + Python, I am trying to work in multiple values to send in a `foreach` loop, so far I am able to send to values, but if I insert looks like the syntax is not correct:

```
lists = {
      'name1' : 'surname1'
      'name2' : 'surname2'
      'name2' : 'surname2'
}
```

What I need to pass to Selenium via `foreach` is this kind of data:

```
lists = {
      'name1' : 'surname1' : 'age1' : 'location1'
      'name2' : 'surname2' : 'age2' : 'location2'
      'name2' : 'surname2' : 'age3' : 'location3'
}
```

I am sure I am doing some bad syntax here, any help?

Comment: `'name1' : 'surname1' : 'age1' : 'location1'` is not valid syntax did you perhaps meant `'name1' : 'surname1' , 'age1' : 'location1'` notice the middle `:` is a comma now?

Comment: What do you want to do with this data?

Answer (score 3):

If you need to group several value sets to use in `for` loop, you can try

```
lists = [['name1', 'surname1', 'age1', 'location1'],
         ['name2', 'surname2', 'age2', 'location2'],
         ['name3', 'surname3', 'age3', 'location3']]
```

and then iterate as

```
for item in lists:
    name = item[0]
    surname = item[1]
    age = item[2]
    location = item[3]
    # do something with all those values
```

or alternatively (preferable):

```
for name, surname, age, location in lists:
    # do something with all those values
```

Answer (score 0):

If `surname`, `age` and `location` are properties/attributes of a person having a `name` then you can achieve this by taking person `name` as a `dictionary key` and rest all other properties as a `list` like this

```
lists = { 
    name1 : [surname1 , age1, location1],
 }
```

and then you can iterate the lists as follows-

```
for key,value in lists: 
    # do something with key 
    for surname,age,location in value: 
        # do something with surname,key,location
```